# Protecting voltage regulator circuit against broken neutral

Tags: voltage-regulator, circuit-protection, darlington

I have a simple voltage regulator. The voltage input is on the left side and the output is on the right side.
Input voltage (Vin) can be as high as 400V (rectified AC) and output voltage (Vout) is regulated to 30Vmax.
The output is used to drive a load connected between Vout and Neutral (N).

But I observed that if the neutral connected to the base of Q3 is broken (but the neutral connected to the load is intact), either Q3/Q1 gets damaged.

Can someone explain why this is happening and how to modify the circuit to fix it? I think I can place a PNP on the left side to protect against this but I don't have any high voltage PNP transistors so any alternative would be welcomed.

[image]

Comment: If the neutral connected to the base of Q3 is broken I'd be more worried about the load getting an over-voltage situation (else why have this regulator?).

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I need basically this circuit to be modified to drop all voltage at the input side if there is a broken neutral. I am okay with the load being shutdown in case of broken neutral. Got ideas?

Comment: Route neutral to the load via ZD2 and make that connection as infallible as you can.

Comment: Can't change load. It's external to my circuit. It's connected to neutral externally.

Comment: Is there an always present minimum load current?

Comment: Not really. The load can be absent also. But I suppose I could add a minimum load current if required.

Answer (score 0):

When the neutral is broken the voltage on the cathode of D22 will rise to near 400V. If the load is attached between D22 and neutral then the current will increase until one or both of the transistors fail. You will be fortunate if the load survives.

A fast acting fuse or current limiter may work.

A fast acting over voltage cut out switch may also work.

Comment: What would be an example of a fasting acting cutout switch for this case for 400V?